# Glob Not Match?

Tags: find, ls

How to list files that don't match a glob?

E.g., let's say I have a directory that contains hundreds of files, 97% of which have the filename extension `.png`.

I know I can list the PNG files with:

```
ls *.png
```

But, how do I list the opposite, i.e., just the non-PNG files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Using ls:

```
ls -I "*.png"
```

the quotes are important to stop the shell evaluating the `*`

#### Using find:

```
find . -not -name "*.png"
```

If you have subdirectories (with files), you may want to limit the search:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name "*.png"
```

where

- `-maxdepth 1` limits it to the present directory
- `-type f` only allows it to print files

Comment: Hmm.. I get `ls: illegal option -- I` on Mac OS X 10.8. But using `find` works. So, thanks! :)

Comment: Interesting, I have no experience with Mac so I can't help there I'm afraid. If this answered your question, though, please can you accept it by pressing the hollow tick next to the answer. Thanks :-)